# Django How to set customize primary key after form is valid

Tags: python, django

I trying to make auto increment of *user_id* after the form is filled. 
It did appear in cleaned_data, but I still can't make register an account.

**forms.py**

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = models.UserProfile
    fields = ['user_name','password','email','birthday','address']

def clean(self):
    user_id = models.UserProfile.user_id
    cleaned_data = super(RegForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data["password"]
    password_confirm = cleaned_data["password_confirm"]
    if user_id == None:
        self.cleaned_data['user_id'] = 1
    else:
        self.cleaned_data['user_id'] = models.UserProfile.objects.count() + 1
    if password != password_confirm:
        raise forms.ValidationError("wrong password")
    return self.cleaned_data

def clean_asset_code(self):
    user_name = self.cleaned_data['user_name']
    if models.UserProfile.objects.filter(user_name=user_name).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user_name already exist.")
    return user_name
```

**views.py**

```
def regist(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    register_form = forms.RegForm(request.POST)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        register_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    register_form = forms.RegForm()
messages.get_messages(request)
template = get_template('regist.html')
request_context = RequestContext(request)
request_context.push(locals())
html = template.render(request_context)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to increase user_id before form is getting validated, I don't think that is a good idea.

**To make an auto increment of user_id**
What you can do is make user_id a primary key field.

> Django Documentation

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False,serialize=True)
```

In this way whenever your form passes all validity pass and when submitted the user_id is automatically incremented.

Comment: Thanks! It did work. But after I created an account, it raised **Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable** when I tried to login!

Comment: add serialize=True in above and check user_id=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False,serialize=True)

Comment: What did you mean "add serialize=True in above", the same result after I add **serialize=True**

Comment: refer the link [Fixing UUID is not JSON serializable](https://arthurpemberton.com/2015/04/fixing-uuid-is-not-json-serializable)